# Visual ++ print from main with inheritance on visual form in listbox

Tags: visual-c++, inheritance, printing, listbox, private-members

I´ve made a "main" class lets call it A(Veichle), 
and i have two classes that inherits from A Lets call them B(Car) and C(MC).
i also have a handler lets call it "D" that binds A,B and C. 
Then i have the Form1 class lets call that E(Visual)

I want to print out the private members from A on the visual form "E" in a Listbox

If i try ex)

this->listbox1->items->add(X.veichles[i]->getBrand());

it complains that veichles is a private member in D.

How can i get around that?

Answer (score 0):

The private means exactly that the access is not allowed for other classes.

You should create a public accessor function. For example, `GetVehicleByIndex(int idx)`.

Your code will look like this:

```
A* pVehicle = X.GetVehicleByIndex(i);
if (pVehicle) // assuming NULL indicates error
    add(pVehicle->getBrand());
else
    // react on error
```

Comment: or using exceptions for error reporting, it can be simple one line: `add(X.GetVehicleByIndex(i).getBrand())`

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question then.

Inside `handler.cpp` in the class class that communicates with `form1.h`, you create a function:

```
void getPersonByIndex(i);

return this->person[i]->getSurName();
```

Then in `form1.h` you write:

```
for(int i=0;i<this->getNrOfPersons;i++)

String^ str = new String(comm.getPersonByIndex(i)); //this conversion was my problem

this->listbox->beginupdate();
this->listbox->items->add(str);
this->listbox->endupdate();
```